# GCP cross account VPC access

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have three separate GCP accounts. One account for productA, one account for productB and one account for devops monitoring. Each account has currently 1 project (more to be added in the future) which has multiple VMs. I want to monitor the VMs (for productA/project and productB/project) from the devops GCP account so I can consolidate the monitoring. The monitoring products are Promethesus, Grafana and Graylog (not GCP).

I am not using organisations at the moment (don't use gsuite or cloud identity)

Do I need VPC networking peering or shared VPC?

Any advice or recommendations on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean 3 projects?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you have 3 google accounts and prodA, prodB and devOps resources under the same project?

Comment: Updated description above. The resources (vm's) are under different account/projects. I want to access productA and productB project resources from the separate devOps account.

Comment: In this case, if you already have a VPC for each project, you might use VPC Peering, for connecting each VPC and monitoring the traffic. Just care about overlapping the traffic.

Comment: Why do you mean by monitoring the VM? Do you want to centralize the logs/metrics in one place for this? If so, what is the relation with the network (VPC) access?

Comment: I want to monitor the VMs using Promethesus, Grafana and Graylog. The devOps GPC account will require access to the productA/VPC and productB/VPC so it can pull metrics etc

Answer (score 0):

[Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) allows an organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network. If your resources are already in different projects, but using the same VPC, the shared VPC concept is already in place.

However, in your case it seems like your resources are using different VPC’s specifically to their own project. Here the concept for [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) can be used regardless of whether they belong to the same project or the same organization. It is possible to set up [VPC Network Peering between two Shared VPC networks](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#shared_vpc). Here is the [Example](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#example_vpc_network_peering_setup) on VPC Network Peering setup.